# How to delete all rows at even indexes in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have dataframe pandas;

```
        Data
  Id    
ID_1    19
ID_2    33
ID_3    17
ID_4    52
ID_5    17
ID_6    41
```

Id is index. how to drop row by index but all of ID with even number?

this is my expected result:

```
        Data
  Id    
ID_1    19
ID_3    17
ID_5    17
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select each even row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[::2]
```

Or filter by mask created by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with modulo 2 and compare by `0`:

```
df1 = df[np.arange(len(df)) % 2 == 0]
print (df1)
      Data
Id        
ID_1    19
ID_3    17
ID_5    17
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without `numpy` would be,

```
df.loc[["ID_" + str(x) for x in range(len(df) + 1) if x % 2 != 0]]
```

or

```
df.filter(items=["ID_" + str(x) for x in range(len(df) + 1) if x % 2 != 0], axis=0)
```